# redirect forms with url values in zend

Tags: zend-framework, redirect, zend-form

I have a page of the format www.test.com/policy-info/

which has a form that takes you to another page www.test.com/payment-info.

Now I am redirecting the page from www.test.com/payment-info to www.test.com/policy-info based on the some values obtained from the form. How do I redirect with certain values in the url.
the filename is policy-info.phtml.

Is this the only way to redirect?
$this->redirect(www.test.com/policy-info/index.phhtml&count=2);

Comment: you said that file name is  policy-info.phtml but from your url  www.test.com/policy-info/index.phtml file name is index.phtml and your controller is policyInfo.php ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
$this->_helper->redirector('action', 'controller', 'module', array('param1'=>'value1', 'param2'=>'value2'));
```

in your case:

```
$this->_helper->redirector('index', 'policy-info', 'default',array('param1'=>'value1', 'param2'=>'value2'));
```

I always use $this->_redirect(...) and that works fine:

```
$this->_redirect('/module/controller/action/param1/value1/param2/value2');
```

Comment: @tasmaniski..my filename is policy-info.phtml..the contolller name is PolicyController.php and action is policyInfoAction. I did not know how to redirect since my url points as www.test.com/policy-info

Comment: so this is what I should do :

$this->_redirect('/PolicyController.php/policyInfoAction/count/1');

Comment: yes, that is third option (my way)... you should do it like this
$this->_redirect('/policy/policy-info/count/1'); I am little confused with your way of doing it...

Answer (score 0):

This may be a case where `_forward()` may be the best choice.

> _forward($action, $controller = null, $module = null, array $params = null): perform another action. If called in preDispatch(), the
>   currently requested action will be skipped in favor of the new one.
>   Otherwise, after the current action is processed, the action requested
>   in _forward() will be executed.

also It looks like you may be using named/defined routes, if that is true gotoRoute maybe useful as well [Redirector Helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelpers.redirector):

`$this->_helper->getHelper('Redirector')->gotoRoute(array('param'=>'value'), 'routeName');`